# Identifying similar url

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary

How would I go with identifying url as identical in path structure.

For example these two counts as identical since they have similar path.

So in my logic, I would say user A has visited `page1/edit` twice.

```
https://example.com/page1/edit/123
https://example.com/page1/edit/321
```

Same as this example,

```
https://example.com/user_id_3455/page2/view/link_213
https://example.com/user_id_23124/page2/view/link_234
```

My initial solution is that I would just split the url and group them by index.

at high level it would be like:

```
 group = {}

 foreach url 
    splitted the url by /
    exclude index 0 - 2 since these are scheme and domain
    group them by index

it would work for work example one since it will result as
{
  page1 : {
            edit: {
                     123: 1 (count)
                     321: 1 
                  }
          }
}
```

So I will just aggregate the child values

but not quite for example 2, any ideas?

Comment: This is difficult to answer without knowing your setup. For example, page1 and page2 are different, but user id 3455 and user id 23124 are the same for this purpose. Are there any fields that matter other than page?

Comment: the example above simulates the difference of URL structure a website may have. Commonly use when you want to render pages dynamically. To answer, your question, I guess no, fields should not matter. Im just struggling to know which path will be dynamic without any user input. Perhaps this is kind of like impossible to know really unless the user tells me so I can add a regex or something.

Answer (score 0):

You could generate a key by removing the parts of the URL that is not relevant to your usage.

Comment: by generating a key, did you mean I will remove  form this use `user_id_3455/page2/view/link_213` ,  user_id_3455 and link_213? So in short the key would be `page2/view`. I gues the issue is that how would I know if the parts are not relevant?

Comment: You tell me. You must have some application in mind, otherwise you would not come up with these examples.